# How to find dependencies when running `react-scripts`

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm launching following build command from my root project, providing `--modules-folder` :

`yarn --modules-folder /usr/local/node_modules/ run react-scripts build`

`react-scripts` is found but then I got :

`./src/index.js
Cannot find module: 'react'. Make sure this package is installed`

However there is follwing folder :

`/usr/local/node_modules/react`

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Possible the flag comes after build? Curious, why build like this?

Comment: no, when i put flag after build, like `yarn run react-scripts build  --modules-folder /usr/local/node_modules/`, it says `react-scripts` is not found